# get text in python3+gtk3

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3

This is possibly more a `python3` question the a `gtk3`.
In this following bit of code, print(numele) is working correctly, i.e. the `connect` function `self.nument.connect("activate",self.get_nument)` is ok.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject

class EntryWindow(Gtk.Window):

  def __init__(self):
    Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Entry Demo")
    self.set_size_request(100, 50)

    grid=Gtk.Grid()
    self.add(grid)

#Create Entry nument
    self.nument = Gtk.Entry()
    self.numlab = Gtk.Label()
    self.numlab.set_text("Number Of Element")
    self.nument.set_text("Number Of Element")
    self.nument.set_editable("TRUE")
    grid.attach(self.numlab, 0,2,1,1)      
    grid.attach(self.nument, 1,2,1,1)      
#Connect Entry nument
    self.nument.connect("activate",self.get_nument)

#Create Entry from numele
    for i in range(1,numele+1):
      self.entry = Gtk.Entry()
      self.entry.set_text("Hello World")
      self.entry.set_editable("FALSE")
      grid.attach(self.entry, 0,2+i,1,1)


    def get_nument(self,entry):
      numele= self.nument.get_text()
      print(numele)

win = EntryWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

But, in the `for loop`, it can not access the numele value.

```
 $python3 hw3.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hw3.py", line 35, in <module>
    win = EntryWindow()
  File "hw3.py", line 24, in __init__
    for i in range(1,numele+1):
NameError: global name 'numele' is not defined
```

I am new to python. So, I am expecting numele is private to the function get_nument. 
What is the best way to use it outside the function(i.e. public)?

Kindly Help.

**EDIT: after ptomato's reply**
I tried exactly that, with:

```
#Connect Entry nument
    self.nument.connect("activate",self.get_nument)
    print(self.numele)
```

and defining the function as:

def get_nument(self,entry):
  self.numele= self.nument.get_text()

Only to have error:

```
$ python3 test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 35, in <module>
    win = EntryWindow()
  File "test.py", line 21, in __init__
    self.nument.connect("activate",self.get_nument)
AttributeError: 'EntryWindow' object has no attribute 'get_nument'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have exactly the right idea. The `numele` variable is locally scoped, so it gets deleted at the end of the function. Either `return` the value from your function, or store it `self.numele` instead. That stores it in your `EntryWindow` object so that it persists beyond the scope of the function.

PS. You might need to do `int(numele)` before you can use it in the `range()` call...

Answer (score 0):

The code has several mistakes and I am not sure what you want to achieve.
You probably want to have some Gtk.Entries based on the number from the first entry. Therefore, you have to move the for-loop into the `get_nument` method. This will still throw an error because `get_nument` is too much indented. Moreover, you need to convert the string from the Gtk.Entry to an integer.
Finally, the grid has to be an attribute to be accessible for `get_nument`.

The result should look like this:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject

class EntryWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Entry Demo")
        self.set_size_request(100, 50)

        self.grid=Gtk.Grid()
        self.add(self.grid)

        #Create Entry nument
        self.nument = Gtk.Entry()
        self.numlab = Gtk.Label()
        self.numlab.set_text("Number Of Element")
        self.nument.set_editable("TRUE")
        self.grid.attach(self.numlab, 0,2,1,1)
        self.grid.attach(self.nument, 1,2,1,1)
        #Connect Entry nument
        self.nument.connect("activate",self.get_nument)



    def get_nument(self,entry):
        numele= self.nument.get_text()
        print(numele)
        #Create Entry from numele
        for i in range(1,int(numele)+1):
            entry = Gtk.Entry()
            entry.set_text("Hello World")
            entry.set_editable("FALSE")
            entry.show()
            self.grid.attach(entry, 0,2+i,1,1)

win = EntryWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

This code still has problems, for example if a lower number is entered, the entries are not removed from the grid.